# WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'http' Error in devtools session

Tags: c#, docker, selenium

I created a new session that Support DevTools Session on docker for selenium 4.
When I make debug, it looks I get all the values to parameters, but when I get to devtools session I get error-WebException: The remote name could not be resolved: 'http'.
what did I miss?

```
RemoteWebDriver dockerChromeDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(DockerPort), dockerChromoptions.ToCapabilities(), remoteDriverTimeOut);
               
var host = new Uri(DockerPort);                     
var sessionId = ((IHasSessionId)dockerChromeDriver).SessionId.ToString();             
var capabilitiesDictionary = (dockerChromeDriver)?.Capabilities.GetFieldValue<Dictionary<string, object>>("capabilities");
capabilitiesDictionary["se:cdp"] = $"ws://{host}/devtools/{sessionId}/page";
capabilitiesDictionary["se:cdpVersion"] = capabilitiesDictionary["browserVersion"];
  
devToolssession = ((IDevTools)dockerChromeDriver).GetDevToolsSession();  // Here I get error when I debugging 
                        
driver = dockerChromeDriver;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the error and stack trace.

Comment: It also doesn't make sense that assigning a variable is throwing this exception. Are you sure it isn't `((IDevTools)dockerChromeDriver).GetDevToolsSession()` that is throwing the exception? Is *"The remote name could not be resolved: 'http'"* the actual message?

Comment: Sorry , my bad, i received the exception on- ((IDevTools)dockerChromeDriver).GetDevToolsSession()

Comment: Which version of Chrome and ChromeDriver are you using?

Comment: Chrome version is - 99.0.4844.51 and Chrome driver version is 98.0.4758.10200

Comment: You need to update ChromeDriver to v99.x. The major versions of Chrome and ChromeDriver need to match.

Comment: But the issue its in docker, Do I still need update the chrome driver?

Comment: Regardless of where you are running Selenium, the major version of Chrome needs to match the major version of ChromeDriver. If the docker container has Chrome v99 and ChromeDriver v98, that is the first thing you need to fix. Otherwise you could be chasing your tail forever.

Answer (score 0):

Running Selenium in a Docker container is not relevant to the issue. In a comment on your question, you mentioned that you are running Chrome version 99.0.4844.51 and ChromeDriver version 98.0.4758.10200. You need to make sure the major versions match. When running Chrome v99.x, you need ChromeDriver v99.x — even when running Selenium in a Docker container.

You likely need to [update ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) in your docker container image.